# How to find solution this system of PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab, maple

> \begin{align} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi &=-h\psi+ie^{-it}\phi &&& (1) \\
> \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\phi&=h\phi+ie^{it}\psi &&& (2) \\
> \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi&=\left(-h-\frac{i}{2}\right)\psi-he^{-it}\phi &&& (3) \\
> \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\phi&=\left(h+\frac{i}{2}\right)\phi-he^{it}\psi &&& (4) 
> \end{align}

Solution of eqs $(1)$-$(4)$ is,

$$\psi=i\left(C_1e^A − C_2e^{−A}\right)e^{− \frac{i}{
2}t}$$ 
$$\phi=\left(-C_1e^{-A} + C_2e^{A}\right)e^{\frac{i}{
2}t}$$

where 
$$C_1 =
\frac{\left(h − \sqrt{h^2 − 1}\right)^{1/2}}
{\sqrt{h^2 − 1}}, \qquad C_2 =
\frac{\left(h + \sqrt{h^2 − 1}\right)^{1/2}}
{\sqrt{h^2 − 1}}$$ and $$A =
\sqrt{h^2 − 1}\big(x + iht\big)$$

How to find these solutions? Anyone can help?

Comment: What is $,\phi$? I mean why do you put the comma there?

Comment: typo mistake...

Comment: Are there any boundary conditions?

Comment: General question: Is it a problem from quantum mechanics?

Comment: One have to be aware that  the expected solutions for $\phi$ and $\psi$ are not the general solutions of eqs (1)-(4). They are particular solutions, probably according to some boundary and/or initial conditions (may be implicitly involved in the context of the problem). So, one cannot give a definitive answer without knowing exactly from which theoretical model the eqs.(1)-(4) are coming from. A partial justification can be obtained thanks to separation of variables, $\phi=f(x)g(t)$ and $\psi=F(x)G(t)$ which might lead to the particular solutions on the expected form.

Comment: I have try it, but cannot solve by seperation of variables, can you explain, how can we seperate  variables $\phi$ and $\psi$.

Comment: @Jacquelin, Can you help, how to solve it by separation of variables?